# How to send messages to a bot using power automate in MS Teams?

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, power-automate

I am trying to test a bot by sending messages and checking its response messages. To Test, I am using "Post message in a chat or channel" in Power Automate,
Post as -> Flow Bot
Post in -> Chat with Flow Bot
In recipient, the bot's name is not visible. It only shows user's name

I am using "Post message in a chat or channel",
Post as -> Flow Bot
Post in -> Chat with Flow Bot
In recipient, the bot name is not visible. It only shows users names. I am expecting bot's name to show up in recipient dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

To send messages to a bot using Power Automate in Microsoft Teams, you will need to do the following:

- Create a Power Automate flow that uses the "Post message in a chat or channel" action.
- In the "Post as" field, choose the "Flow Bot" option. This will ensure that the message is sent from the Flow Bot account, which is the account used by Power Automate to send messages.
- In the "Post in" field, choose the "Chat with Flow Bot" option. This will ensure that the message is sent to the Flow Bot, which is the account that will receive the message.
- In the "Recipient" field, you should be able to select the name of the bot that you want to send the message to. If you do not see the name of the bot in the dropdown list, you may need to check that the bot is installed and configured properly in Microsoft Teams.
- After you have selected the recipient, you can enter the message that you want to send in the "Message" field. You can also use dynamic content to insert information from previous steps in the flow, if needed.
- Save and run the flow to test it. The Flow Bot should send the message to the bot that you selected, and you should be able to see the bot's response in Microsoft Teams.